# Set value in django filter filterset_fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm doing a filter search. In my view, I have implemented filtering, I need to check the permission, and if it is equal to is_partner then filtering by partnerId__user__id should be = user_id, else is my entered value. How can I implement this? I can't figure out how to access the filter and set its value.

my code

### models

```
class Partner(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(AbstractUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  primary_key=True, related_name='user')
    objects = BaseManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "userPartner"
        permissions = (
            ("is_partner", "Partner user"),
        )

class Event(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        _('title'),
        max_length=255,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        _('description'),
    )
    enabled = models.BooleanField(
        _('enabled or disabled')
    )
    partnerId = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
```

### view

```
class SerarchParnterEvents(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(enabled=True)
    permission_classes = [ProjectPermission.IsPartner | ProjectPermission.IsAdmin]
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']
    filterset_fields = ['partnerId__user__id']

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        if request.user.has_perm('User.is_partner'):
            ???????
```

### serializer

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'enabled', 'partnerId'
                  )
        extra_kwargs = {"partnerId": {'read_only': True},
                        }
```